# Calculating Plane equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Three dots P1, P2, P3 (see image) lie on a plane $\Pi$. Calculate the equation of the plane, using an *normal vector*.

All info including my attempt is in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your method is *almost* correct but I feel you have made a mistake when writing down $P_3$. The easiest way to check is to substitute the 3 points in your and the "correct" equation. Ideally, since the plane passes through those points, the three points should satisfy the equation of the plane. For the correct equation, the first two satisfy LHS=RHS, the last one does not.

However, in any case, your method is *almost* correct. You have made an error when computing the 2nd determinant. (You missed the 2 when multiplying 18). You have the right idea though.

Comment: Is $16x-31y+z+25=0$ correct?

Comment: I believe so. (You can simply substitute for the 3 points and see if the RHS is really zero. A quick mental calculation suggests this answer is correct assuming $P_3$ is copied down correctly).